# Accidentally enabled iAds in my paid iPhone App

Tags: iphone, app-store-connect, iad

While submitting my iPhone App ( Paid version ) I accidentally enabled iAds in iTunes Connect. However, there is no code to support iAd in my application. I tried doing what iTunes Connect said, which was to upload a new binary... but it still says iAds are enabled. Will my app be rejected? If not, will iAds be showing up on my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ads won't show since there is no code to support them in your app: enabling ads just mean your application can ask for them.

I don't think it will be a problem for the app to be approved, but not sure about it

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll let you know what happens to my app.

Comment: If anyone else has this problem, don't worry! Apple has accepted my app today ( the paid one that I accidentally enabled iAds on ) Check it out here! https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/instameme-create-memes-free/id578523295?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4